# UTF-8 characters handling in docker from intellij idea

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I recently upgraded my version of Docker on Windows 10 to Docker Desktop version 4.20.1 (110738). Hence intellij (updated) manifests strange characters when I run my conteiners:

[image]

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA  2023.1.3

Comment: Could you please check the issue with 2023.2 version? If the issue still the same please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.